# save result from Google Place Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ionic3

If I type in Atl then GooglePlace autocomplete shows a list of matching results which I can select for the input field.  The problem is I'm not sure where this is captured in order to store it in the backend.  If I console.log("location") then it only gives me the text I actually entered.  So even if I select the entire name Atlanta, Ga after typing "Atl" the location only captures "ATL".

Here is my HTML input field:

```
          <input [(ngModel)]="location" id="places" type="text" 
          name="search" placeholder="Enter city" #search>
```

Here is the code that's returning the places based on the text entered in the input:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.mapsApiLoader.load().then(
  () => {
    let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElement.nativeElement, {types:['(cities)']});

    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

        if(place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null){
          return;
        }
      });
    });
  }
)
```

}

How do I save the full city name instead of only the text I entered?  I want the text I choose from the dropdown.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a result from the dropdown and the `place_changed` event is fired, the Autocomplete widget returns a [`PlaceResult`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlaceResult) object. You can either get the city name itself with the [`name`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlaceResult.name) or the city, state, country with the [`formatted_address`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlaceResult.formatted_address) field. The following code snippet adapted from your code:

```
let cityNameString = '';
let cityFullString = '';

let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
  return;
} else {
  cityNameString = place.name;
  cityFullString = place.formatted_address;
  // Do stuff with the strings
}
```

Comment: From what I read, you can use `address_components` (an array). See it referenced here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete